# is there an alternative to onfocusout() function?

Tags: javascript, input, onfocusout

I have a function `onfocusout()` that runs another function `selectEntite()` inside an input like the following code  :

```
<input onfocusout="selectEntite();" type="text" placeholder="Entité" id="entityName" class="inputSelect" name="entityName" style="width: 60%" />
```

when the user leave the input, the function run. I want to change this behaviour by making it run when the user tap the keyboard enter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input onkeydown="selectEntite(this);" type="text" placeholder="Entité" id="entityName" class="inputSelect" name="entityName" style="width: 60%" />
```

```
function selectEntite(ele) {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
        alert(ele.value);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add an addEventListener() to the input field that listens for key presses. Then check if enter is pressed, then you can execute some code. –

```
let el = document.getElementById("entityName")
el.addEventListener("keydown",(event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        // Enter key was hit
    }
})
```